# How to permanently remove the "read only" feature on an excel file in vb.net no matter how many time the event procedure is run

Tags: excel, vb.net

I posted a similar question above almost two weeks ago. It has almost 100 views so far and yet no comments. I've done very careful research during this time as well as prior to posting the question so I am sure it is not for lack of clarity or a perception of triviality. During my research and associated trial and error process, I've experienced many variations of results (as well as errors) but none was exactly correct so I wanted to share my observations so far to see if it would trigger an insight in someone.

I am simply trying to allow users of my software who have been granted administrative status to verify their login credentials and then change it by pressing the "Reset" button. I already have about 10 users in my excel-based database with 3 of them granted administrative privileges. This database is contained at "Path" in the code below. Various case scenario's are presented in which incomplete user credentials are supplied and the code to handle such scenario's is also provided beneath.
In the case of individuals granted administrative privileges, everything in the code works until the changes are required to be saved into the excel database. This is when the program imposes a read-only status on the excel file containing the data, which cannot be removed by code and triggers an error. Beneath is the entire code for the "but_Reset_Click" event procedure which is supposed to verify the users administrative status and based on that, grant him/her access to change his/her credentials as many times as he/she wants with no issues. Attached is a snapshot of the error message I receive.[image: Error Message]

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butReset.Click
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\Research\Current Research\Automating the GSRS\GSRS 
    with horizontal curve v 1.0\bin\Debug\Usernames.xlsx"
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.activate()
    sheetCount = oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(XlDirection.xlUp).row
    initialusername = "admin"
    initialpassword = "password"
    adminusername = InputBox("Please Enter admin username", "Alert")
    adminpassword = InputBox("Please Enter admin password", "Alert")
    usernameverify = InputBox("Please Enter new admin username", "Alert")
    passwordverify = InputBox("Please Enter new admin password", "Alert")
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = True And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) =True
        MsgBox("You are not authorized to reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
        Exit Do
    Loop
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
    False
        For j = 2 To sheetCount
            ReDim Preserve usernames(j)
            If oSheet.Cells(j, 5).Text = "Administrator" Then
                usernames(j) = oSheet.Cells(j, 3).Text
            End If
        Next
        For k = 2 To sheetCount
            ReDim Preserve passwords(k)
            If oSheet.Cells(k, 5).Text = "Administrator" Then
                passwords(k) = oSheet.Cells(k, 4).Text
            End If
        Next

        For Each username As String In usernames
            For Each password As String In passwords

       If (adminusername = initialusername Or adminusername = username) And (adminpassword = 
           initialpassword Or adminpassword = password) Then
                    oSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = usernameverify
                    oSheet.Cells(k, 4).Value = passwordverify
                  Dim filefinal As IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("Usernames.xlsx")
                    filefinal.IsReadOnly = False
                    oBook.SaveAs(Path)
                    MsgBox("Administrator credentials have been updated",, "Success")
                    oExcel.Workbooks.Close()
                    oExcel.Quit()
                    Me.txtusername.Text = ""
                    Me.txtpassword.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Next
        Next
    Loop
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
        False
        For j = 2 To sheetCount
            For k = 2 To sheetCount
      If oSheet.Cells(j, 5).Text = "Administrator" Or oSheet.Cells(k, 5).Text = "Administrator" Then
                    ReDim Preserve usernames(j)
                    ReDim Preserve passwords(k)
                    usernames(j) = oSheet.Cells(j, 3).Text
                    passwords(k) = oSheet.Cells(k, 4).Text
                End If
            Next
        Next
  For Each username As String In usernames
  For Each password As String In passwords
  If (adminusername <> initialusername Or adminusername <> username) And (adminpassword <> 
      initialpassword Or adminpassword <> password) Then
                    MsgBox("You are Not authorized To reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
                    oExcel.Workbooks.Close()
                    oExcel.Quit()
                    Me.txtusername.Text = ""
                    Me.txtpassword.Text = ""
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Loop
      Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = True And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
    False
        MsgBox("You are Not authorized To reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
        Exit Do
    Loop
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
     True
        MsgBox("You are Not authorized To reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
        Exit Do
    Loop
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = True And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
     False
        MsgBox("You are Not authorized To reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
        Exit Do
    Loop
    Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminusername) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminpassword) = 
    True
        MsgBox("You are Not authorized To reset the login credentials!",, "Alert")
        Exit Do
    Loop
    Me.txtusername.Text = ""
    Me.txtpassword.Text = ""
End Sub
```

`

"oBook.Save(Path)" is the code section which triggers the following error;

Comment: Why use Excel for a shared database?  I'm pretty sure that is going to be the source of you issue, Excel is really designed with single user in mind    There plenty of better options around that would be far better suited to a multi user environment (SQL Server, MySQL, MS Access)

Comment: @Hursey, you're absolutely right. This specific version is merely a proof of concept for an engineering software for academic purposes. Hence I mostly used list-boxes to display data and import and export data from and to text and excel files. Version 2 will be built with standard features. I was just hoping to jump this hurdle and get approval before actually getting into the meat of the product.

Comment: Sorry, not meaning to tell you how to do your job, but even as a proof of concept, really it just makes sense to do it right from the outset.  As you've stated you've been on this for nearly 2 weeks now, where as it probably would be less than a couple hours work to just implement a multi user db

Comment: @Hursey, you're probably right.

Comment: @Mary. I would like to request your expertise at an adjacency to the above problem as I managed to solve it eventually. 
I am trying to implement a reset feature in the administrative module of my application such that once a user has already been granted administrative access at the time the user was added to the excel database, and said username and password associated with the user are requested for and verified when the reset button is clicked, the application replaces the old username and password respectively of the said user when that information is requested after verification.